# How do I convert a string of the form 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:MI:SS.MS +00:00' where last four chars are a timezone offset into a postgres timestamptz?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

How do I convert a string of the form 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:MI:SS.MS +00:00' where last four chars are a timezone offset into a postgres timestamptz?

This does not seem to work:

```
select '2018-06-13 04:11:46.873 -07:00'::timestamptz;
        timestamptz         
----------------------------
 2018-06-13 11:11:46.873+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Looks correct to me (assuming your local time zone is UTC)

Comment: It's best to explain exactly what you wanted to happen, rather than saying something "doesn't work". Clearly, "04:11 -07" and "11:11 +00" are *equivalent*, so it is "working" in that sense. I'm guessing the confusion here is how to display the timestamp with its original time zone information, rather than converted to UTC.

Comment: Damn, I want to thank you @IMSoP for spotting what I missed for at least an hour. 
Again, thanks to both of you.

Comment: FWIW, @a_horse_with_no_name, I was expecting to see the -07 translated over into the timezone field, not the 04 o'clock turn into 11 o'clock. Your comment about the server being local UTC is absolutely correct and helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct. The type `timestamp with time zone` is a bit misleading and the behaviour is different than e.g. in Oracle.

[quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.19.7)

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone.

The input `'2018-06-13 04:11:46.873 -07:00'::timestamptz` is converted to the corresponding UTC value based on the time zone offset given. *That* value is then convert to your session time zone and sent to the client which then results in `2018-06-13 11:11:46.873+00` in your session's time zone.